# Snowflake sql select query automation

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have built a data engineering pipeline in snowflake SQL environment. Output of these pipelines is used in our data science model.

```
Code is organized as ( Step 1,2,3 are SQL queries) :- 
Step 1 query - input is raw data table
Step 2 query - input is output of Step 1 view
Step 3 query - input is output of Step 2  view
```

Output of Step 3 is final output.

For automation, I am planning to create SQL view for step 1,2 and 3.

**Question- if I use SQL view , when I do select * from step3 view, would it run step 1 and 2 ?  I want the code to run step 1 and 2 code everytime I pull data from step 3.Is there any other way of automating this? I am new to snowflake environment, do I have to take care of materialized or non-materialized view?**

Comment: Can you be little more elaborate and share the SQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views are evaluated at *query* time.  If you set up the logic using views, then the queries will be processed in the ordered needed to generate the correct result set.

One downside to views is that if they are referenced more than once, then the logic may be repeated.

Comment: Thank you, I am using each view once. In case if we have same view being referenced multiple times, would you recommend some other way of automating this?

Comment: @ank12 . . . The problem you are trying to solve is tricky.  I would materialize the views in a production system.